# Odoo-8 Dynamically add the URL Address

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Good Day! I have this problem I've create a Link in my Odoo Website Website Recruitment

with url link

```
str_url = 'http://localhost:8069'+'/web/binary/saveas?model=ir.attachment&field=datas&filename_field=name&id='+str(attachment.id)
```

But I want in the 'http://localhost:8069' is the exact url address. because when I run this code in other machine It will raise an Error.

Is there way to get the Exact URL Address?

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Answer just used the

```
request.httprequest.host_url
```

and it would be like this

```
str_url = request.httprequest.host_url +'web/binary/saveas?model=ir.attachment&field=datas&filename_field=name&id='+str(attachment.id)
```

Hope I can Help :D